# An inequality for sides of a triangle

Tags: geometry, inequality, contest-math, triangles, geometric-inequalities

Let $ a, b, c $ be sides of a triangle and $ ab+bc+ca=1 $. Show
$$(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)<4 $$

I tried Ravi substitution and got a close bound, but don't know how to make it all the way to $4 $.
I am looking for a non-calculus solution (no Lagrange multipliers).

Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Nice problem. However, can anybody make a geometric sense to $ab+bc+ca$ and to $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WOLOG assume that $a\geq b\geq c>0$. The constraints the problem imposes are $c=\frac{1-ab}{a+b}$, $b+c>a$. Equivalently, we have $\frac{1-ab}{a+b}+b > a\geq b$ and $b\geq \frac{1-ab}{a+b}$. These inequalities yield $$0\leq a^2-b^2<1-ab<1\quad (1)$$ and $$ab\geq \frac{1-b^2}{2}.\quad(2)$$

Note that $(1)$ implies $0<b\leq a<1$. Now, suppose that $a+b\leq 1$. Then from $(2)$ we have $2b\geq 2b(a+b)\geq 1+b^2$, which is not possible since $b<1$. Thus, we must have $$a+b>1.\quad (3)$$ Invoking $(3)$ we have 
$$(1-a)(1-b)>0\\
\implies ab>a+b-1\\
=\left\vert a+b-1\right\vert\\
\implies a^2b^2>(a+b-1)^2\\
\iff 1-a^2b^2<2(a+b)-(a+b)^2\\
\iff a+b+(1+ab)\frac{1-ab}{a+b}<2\\
\iff a+b+c +abc<2\\
\implies (1+a)(1+b)(1+c)<4.$$

Answer (score 3):

Solving $ab+bc+ca=1$ for $c$ gives
$$
c=\frac{1-ab}{a+b}\tag{1}
$$
The triangle inequality says that for non-degenerate triangles
$$
|a-b|\lt c\lt(a+b)\tag{2}
$$
Multiply $(2)$ by $a+b$ to get
$$
|a^2-b^2|\lt1-ab\lt(a+b)^2\tag{3}
$$
By $(3)$, we have $(a+b)^2-1+ab\gt0$; therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
(a+b+1)(a+b+ab-1)
&=\left[(a+b)^2-1+ab\right]+(a+b)ab\\
&\gt(a+b)ab\\[6pt]
&\gt0\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore, $\color{#C00000}{(3)}$ implies
$$
a\ge1\implies1-b^2\le\color{#C00000}{a^2-b^2\lt1-ab}\implies b\gt a\tag{5a}
$$
Similarly,
$$
b\ge1\implies1-a^2\le\color{#C00000}{b^2-a^2\lt1-ab}\implies a\gt b\tag{5b}
$$
Inequalities $(5)$ imply that if either $a\ge1$ or $b\ge1$, then both $a\gt1$ and $b\gt1$. Consequently, we have both $a\gt b$ and $b\gt a$. Therefore, we must have
$$
a\lt1\qquad\text{and}\qquad b\lt1\tag{6}
$$
Using $(1)$, $(4)$, and $(6)$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
abc+a+b+c-2
&=(1+ab)\frac{1-ab}{a+b}+(a+b)-2\\
&=\frac{1-a^2b^2+(a+b)^2-2(a+b)}{a+b}\\
&=\frac{(a+b-1)^2-a^2b^2}{a+b}\\
&=\frac{(a+b+ab-1)(a+b-ab-1)}{a+b}\\
&=-\frac{(a+b+ab-1)(a-1)(b-1)}{a+b}\\
&\lt0\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, since $ab+bc+ca+1=2$, $(7)$ says
$$
\begin{align}
(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)
&=(abc+a+b+c)+(ab+bc+ca+1)\\[4pt]
&\lt2+2\\[4pt]
&=4\tag{8}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: In fact, a maximum occurs for the degenerate triangle $a=1, b=1, c=0$, which gives $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)=4$

Comment: @user58697: Since I noticed the OP requested a non-calculus solution, I scrapped the variational approach and reworked my original approach. Not allowing degenerate triangles, I now get $\lt4$.

Answer (score 0):

$(1+a)(1+b)(1+c) = 2 + a+b+c + abc < 2 + 2(a+b) + ab(a+b) = 2 + (a+b)(2 + ab)$ (because $c < a+b)$

$ab + bc + ac = ab + (a+b)c < ab + (a+b)^2$ for the same reason, that is $ab > 1 - (a+b)^2$, and $2 + ab > 3 - (a+b)^2$

Combining, we have $(1+a)(1+b)(1+c) < 2 + 3(a+b) - (a+b)^3$

The latter achieves the maximum 4 at $a+b = 1$ (we are not interested in negative $a+b$), QED

Comment: I think you got one inequality wrong: $ab>1-(a+b)^2$.

Comment: @S.B. Of course, you right. Edited.

Comment: You applied one inequality in the wrong direction.