# BMO1 2010-11 Q6

Tags: inequality, contest-math, geometric-inequalities

I have attempted this question but I believe there is a better way of doing this. Please leave some comment on how I should improve my answer/ alternative ways of doing it. Thanks!

**Question:**

Let $a, b, c$ be the lengths of the sides of a triangle. Suppose that $ab + bc + ca = 1$. Show that $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)< 4$.

**My attempt:**

Sides of the triangle add up to a perimeter $x : a+b+c=x$

Equivalently, $(a+1) + (b+1) + (c+1) = x + 3$

By triangle inequality, assuming $a+b>c$. Equivalently, $(a+1)+(b+1) > c+1$.

For the case $(a+1) + (b+1) + (c+1)$, since the addition of the sides of the triangle are less than the sides of the triangles multiplied, we are sure that if  $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)< 4$, with our assumption above we can safely assume that $(a+1) + (b+1) + (c+1)<4 $ :

$(a+1) + (b+1) + (c+1) = x+3< 4$ *or* $x+3<4$.

We now know that $x\leq 1$ (the perimeter of the sides $a,b,c$ are lesser than 1), hence we know that for all value of $a,b,c \leq 1$ the statement  holds.

Comment: You wrote "the addition of the sides of the triangle are less than the sides of the triangles multiplied". It is false in general (think about a triangle whose all sides are $\le 1$).

Comment: As for the alternative ways, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/681433/an-inequality-for-sides-of-a-triangle and https://bmos.ukmt.org.uk/solutions/bmo1-2011/.

Comment: Hi! I should have stated it more clearly that the assumption is based on the case (a+1)+(b+1)+(c+1) instead of a+b+c.

Comment: Please rewrite your solution. I have similar concerns as Vahe. E.g. Are you looking at $ \sum (a+1)(b+1)$?

Comment: Hi! I have edited some parts to explain more of my steps. Sorry about that.

Comment: It looks to me that you are saying "Assuming that the product (of terms greater than 1) is less than 4, then the sum is less than 4". This need not be true, like $ a+1 = b+1 = c+1 = \sqrt[3]{4} \approx 1.59$. Note also that even if we have $ a < 1$, all that we can conclude is $ \prod(a+1) < 8 $. (And this approach runs the risk of a cyclic argument. In general, you shouldn't assume X to prove X)